# Unix to tail solution for waiting for a specific string or quitting after a timeout

Tags: sed, grep, tail

I am trying to improve a service (daemon) script to display tomcat output (when run from a tty) until the application is effectively started.

Tomcat apps can take up to 10 minutes to start and it's extremely useful to see what happens.

Still, we need to be sure that this startup script will not run indefinitely if the startup confirmation message is failing to appear in the logs.

I know that the internet is full of similar questions, but so far I wasn't able to identify a clear solution, especially one that works without requiring utilities that are not available by default.

Requirements:

1. run without requiring you to install anything on recent Debian, Ubuntu, RedHat and OS X
2. no processes left behind when it ends (due to any reason)
3. display the logged lines to stdout
4. log file is readonly, you cannot touch it
5. log file can be rotated without breaking the tool
6. extra kudos if you can make it work in one line

Identified problems so far:

- `read -t` not available on current Debian, `Illegal option -t`

References to partial solutions so far:

- [Shell function to tail a log file for a specific string for a specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13983572/shell-function-to-tail-a-log-file-for-a-specific-string-for-a-specific-time)

Comment: To clarify: you want a "command string" that monitors a (log) file for a certain time before exiting, and which will print the found string to stdout and quit if found. Do you need output on timeout?

Comment: I followed your link. What did you not like about Tony K's solution given there? It seemed to meet all your criteria, so I am missing something.

Comment: Did my updated solution work? I'm curious... :)

Comment: @msb I want to thank you. To some extend it worked but I had some weird problems with and that's why I am not currently using it. I will have to dig it further. Now I think that the requirement of having it as single line was not needed. Anyway, I will be back when I have it fixed.

Comment: Good, glad to help. And you may still get further help... you may give me more details of what problems you're having, or you can accept my answer and open another one if you think it's an issue that would change the essence of this question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a script to monitor the tomcat output waiting for a specific string, the solution below should work, and it doesn't use `read -t`.

```
( tail -f server.log & ( (tail -f server.log | grep -l STARTED && kill -9 `pstree -pa $$ | grep -E '\-(tail|sleep),' | sed 's/^[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\).*/\1/' | grep -vw $$ | xargs` ) & sleep 900 && kill -9 `pstree -pa $$ | grep -E '\-(tail|sleep),' | sed 's/^[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\).*/\1/' | grep -vw $$ | xargs` && exit 3 ) ) ; [ $? -eq 3 ]  && echo 'server not up after 5 min'  || echo 'server up'
```

It is searching for the string "*STARTED*" inside the log file *server.log*, with a timeout of 15 minutes (900 seconds).
I'm not sure what you have available in your Debian. You should have `pstree`, whose output should be similar to:

```
$ pstree -pa 1803
bash,1803
  └─bash,7850
      ├─bash,7852
      │   ├─bash,7853
      │   │   ├─grep,7856 --color=auto -l STARTED
      │   │   └─tail,7855 -f server.log
      │   └─sleep,7854 20
      └─tail,7851 -f server.log
```

The rest I'm sure you should have: `kill`, `sed`, `sleep`, `grep`, `echo`, `xargs`.

Some explanation of what is happening. This line contains one command and the final evaluation of the command results, to print if the server is up or not. The command is divided in 3 parts:

1. simply output the log content, as requested.
2. monitor the output looking for the specific string "*STARTED*"; if found, `kill` parts 1 and 3.
3. wait for 15 minutes, and if 15 minutes pass, `kill` parts 1 and 2,
   exiting with code 3 to signal to the outside evaluation that the
   whole command ended due to timeout.

With comments:

```
( tail -f server.log & # part 1 - just output the log content
  ( # part 2
    (tail -f server.log | grep -l STARTED # search for the string
     && kill -9 `pstree -pa $$ | grep -E '\-(tail|sleep),' | 
        sed 's/^[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\).*/\1/' | grep -vw $$ | 
        xargs` # if found, kill the remaining tails and sleeps
    ) & # if the command ends in part 2, exit code is not 3
  sleep 900 # part 3: sleep 15 minutes
  && kill -9 `pstree -pa $$ | grep -E '\-(tail|sleep),' | 
              sed 's/^[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\).*/\1/' | grep -vw $$ | 
              xargs` # if time passed, kill the remaining tails and sleeps
  && exit 3 # exit with code 3, so that the outside evaluation 
            # knows it ended by timeout
  )
) ; # end of command; whenever it finishes, the evaluation below is executed, 
    # checking the exit code to print the appropriate message
[ $? -eq 3 ]  && echo 'server not up after 5 min'  || echo 'server up'
```

Note that, due to how `bash` pipes work, if the "*STARTED*" string is found the command will actually only exit and print the message "*server up*" after an extra line is added to *server.log* after the line with "*STARTED*". That's because when the line "*STARTED*" is printed, `grep` will find it, print its output and exit, closing its input. However, the corresponding `tail` will continue to run until it has something else to write; only then `tail` will realize its output is closed, and then will die, moving on to the `kill` command that will lead to the evaluation. There's no workaround to that, AFAIK. You should make sure something is printed to the log after the "*STARTED*" message, if it's not already.

Comment: I'm not sure if this works, I tried it but I didn't see any output from the logs, I guess something went wrong.

Comment: The command won't output anything until the string "STARTED" appears in the logs or the timeout time is reached. It will only output "server up", when the string "STARTED" appears in the log file; or it will output "server not up after 5 min" if 5 minutes passed and the string was not seen. What other output do you want?

Comment: It would be great if you could add a version that outputs the log to stdout so you can see what happens.

Comment: @sorin I changed it to incorporate the output, and added some explanation of what is happening so that you can adapt it yourself in case you need something slightly different.