# Do a tail -F until matching a pattern (with no error)

Tags: macos, bash, shell, sed, tail

I have a line working from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024357/do-a-tail-f-until-matching-a-pattern) that tails a file until a matching pattern is found.  It works well, but I can't find a way to suppress the output that occurs afterwards.
The line is:

```
sh -c 'tail -n +0 -f $logfile | { sed "/EOF/ q" && kill $$ ;}'
```

piping to /dev/null doesn't work as I don't get any output at all from the tail command that way.  Also, I'm on OSX and various other sed and awk suggestions don't work due to the syntax.

It always finishes with the below, instead of nothing:
sh: line 10: 14285 Terminated: 15          sh -c 'tail -n +0 -f $logfile | { sed "/EOF/ q" && kill $$ ;}'

I'd also like not to display the matched text (EOF in the above example).
Any suggestions welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually discard the stderr like this:

```
sh -c 'tail -n +0 -f $logfile | { sed "/EOF/q" && p=$$ && kill $((p+1)) ; }'
```

Comment: Thanks, that was worth a try but unfortunately didn't work.  The error still displays:   sh: line 11: 14864 Terminated: 15          sh -c 'tail -n +0 -f $logfile | { sed "/EOF/ q" && kill $$ ;}' 2> /dev/null

Comment: sh: line 13: 83905 Terminated: 15          sh -c 'tail -n +0 -f $logfile 2>/dev/null | { sed "/EOF/ q" && kill $$ ;}'               It's most strange!  Thanks for your help though , appreciated.

Comment: sh: line 14: 92708 Terminated: 15          sh -c 'tail -n +0 -f $logfile | { sed "/EOF/ q" && kill $$ > /dev/null 2>&1 ;}'         I wonder if it's something to do with the sh command itself..  very odd.  Thanks again though.    I'm going to perhaps look for a completely different way again.  I'm not bothered about the code being over multiple lines etc.

Comment: Yes thanks, but unfortunately with this code it never actually ends (although EOF is added to the file).

Comment: That's very strange since I tested it on my osx with a real log file.

Answer (score 0):

for a file (log for example)

```
sed -u "/pattern/ q" YourFile
```

for a pipe

```
ls -l | sed -u "/pattern/ q"
```

the -u of sed tell it to work as a stream input

Comment: OSX gives me this:  sed: illegal option -- u

Comment: sed use a buffer by default so in stream input, it can reach the buffer limit if part of the action keep pattern in memory. Try without the -u it still should work but sometime on line input just after your pattern (buffer)

Comment: Without the -u it just reads the file as is, then quits.  It doesn't wait for any pattern first.   Not sure why OSX doesn't like the -u option.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It's the shell's job monitoring popping the message.

```
nomonitor() {
    set +m
    "$@"
    set -m
}
nomonitor sh -c 'tail -n +0 -f $logfile | { sed "/EOF/ q" && kill $$; }'
```

Comment: Thanks.  I don't quite understand that, but it gives me:  sh: line 13: 17622 Terminated: 15          "$@"