# tail and grep + print and exit first match

Tags: linux, bash, grep, tail

I'm looking for a 1 liner to tail a file and grep a "string", print the first match (new line) and exit.

I came up with:

```
tail -f /var/log/logfile.log -n 0 | grep -m 1 -i string_to_match
```

actual result is that the command prints the first match but exits only after the second match.
any help would be appreciated

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024357/do-a-tail-f-until-matching-a-pattern which also has a link to Superuser with more solutions.

Comment: Heh. So, `grep` exits immediately, but `tail` doesn't *know* that `grep` exited until it tries to write a second line and gets a SIGPIPE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Bash you could use:

```
$ grep -m 1 string_to_match <(tail -n 0 -f file)
```

This could work for testing (NOTICE: IT APPENDS TO A FILE NAMED `file`):

```
$ grep -m 1 foo <(tail -n 0 -f file) & sleep 2 ; echo -e bar\\nfoo >> file
[1] 5390
foo
[1]+  Done                    grep --color -m 1 foo <(tail -n 0 -f file)
```

**Edit**: Further testing revealed that `tail` stays running in the background but exits after the next line in the file.

Comment: Humm, pretty hard to make a one-liner for testing.

Comment: thanks, this one gives syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: @IsaacA: You don't use `bash`.

Comment: @Cyrus GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release

Comment: @Tiw cant use perl :(

Comment: @Cyrus Ive edited your suggestion to:    grep -m 1 urlfilter <$(tail -n 0 -f /var/log/alert1.log) but it does not print and does not exits... just sits there....

Comment: @IsaacA: I can't reproduce the error you mentioned with [bash-3.2.57](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-3.2.57.tar.gz). It occurs when using `sh`.

Comment: If targeting a new enough version of bash, command substitutions' PIDs will be put in `$!` so you can kill them explicitly, so don't need to wait for the later match/exit. I want to say that's version 4.3 or therebouts.

Comment: @JamesBrown Eventually what you suggested was the right answer for me! Thanks and thank you all!  grep -m 1 string_to_match <(tail -n 0 -f /var/log/syslog.log)