# How do I get sed to quit on the first match and not after?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, watch

A background process is writing to a log and I want to output all text from this log to the terminal, up until the word "Do".

I'm using this command:

```sh
tail -f service.log | sed '/Do/ q'
```

For some reason, this command will output the word "Do" and wait until the next line is written to the log *before* it quits.

To verify, I ran my command and then manually appended to the file using the following commands in another window:

```
echo A >> service.log
# outputs 'A' in the sed window
echo B >> service.log
# outputs 'B' in the sed window
echo C >> service.log
# outputs 'C' in the sed window
echo Do >> service.log
# outputs 'Do' in the sed window, but the tail and sed command is still running.
echo E >> service.log
# now the tail and sed command finishes.
```

sed seems to quit only after the next line is written to the file, not when it was outputted.

How do I make my sed command quit on the first output of the word 'Do'?

Comment: Which sed is this? I can't reproduce the lingering with GNU sed 4.7

Comment: My sed version is 4.2.2

Comment: As a work-around, you could try a Perl equivalent `perl -pe '/Do/ && exit'`

Comment: Thank you Mark, but the perl command has the same behavior as sed.

Comment: Which sed is this? You say it is sed 4.2.2, but is it GNU sed? Check it out with `sed --version`.

Comment: Aha, the linked duplicate question tells us it's the fault of `bash`.

Comment: For future code-archeologists, the selected and most popular answer in the linked duplicate question will also kill your wrapping command script. Instead, https://stackoverflow.com/a/10142209/1204024 somehow fixed my issue without killing my script. I'm not sure so if it does by working around `bash`

Comment: Any ideas on why `tail -f service.log | sed '/Do/ q'` will wait until after a new line is written to quit, versus `sed '/Do/q' <(tail -f service.log)`? They seem semantically equivalent.

Comment: Try `sed '/Do/,$d'`

Answer (score -1):

Try with capital Q

```
sed '/Compiled/Q'
```

@rodentry, you're right. How about

```
sed 's/Do/\n/' | head -1
```

Or the solution must be `sed` only?

Comment: Thank you but the only change is that "Do" does not output at all. The sed command still waits until after a new line is appended to the log to quit.

Comment: That will do just the same, except it won't print the last line.

Comment: This works for me: `sed '/Do/,$d'`